# stopping application after some time

Tags: java, time

I want to do some calculation, but if they took too much time(say 10 sec), I want to stop it and show current best result.

Is it ready way to do it in Java? I don't want to write time checking in every function.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html Does this help at all?

Comment: *"I don't want.."*  Why should we care what you want?  It's what works that matters.  Can you come up with a better reason to give your question attention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Timer` as suggested or go for multiple threads. In your main program, another thread with the calculation is started. The main thread sleeps via `Thread.sleep` and terminates the calculation after the timeout.

```
main thread +-------+---sleeping---termination----+
                    |                 |
another thread      +---calculation---+
```

Comment: When you do it that way, the calculation will always take ten seconds. That is very inefficient.

Comment: You're right. Unless you let the calculation interrupt the sleeping thread after completing calculation.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a separate thread that you can start at the beginning of your calculation thread, and after 10 seconds with the Timer.sleep(int) method, set a boolean value to true. Then in the calculation thread, `if(finished) break;`

Answer (score -1):

Have another thread with a loop that increments a value every second, and then exits at 10 seconds.

```
public class counter extends Thread, implements Runnable{
 public void run()
{
 for(int index=0; index<10; index++)//Waits ten seconds
{
this.sleep(1000);//ms
}
System.exit(0);//Closes the application
}
```

The main Thread can still execute, though. To cancel the shutdown I suppose you could have a volatile boolean that gets set to true if input was recieved in time.

Comment: It's very unclear how this code contributes to a solution. Furthermore it's sufficient to extend `Thread` **or** implement `Runnable`.